# React JS fetching data (error: Cannot read properties of undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

i am just trying to learn JavaScript. I have to create a web application for school. Now i am trying to fetch data from a self written api. The backend is written with express, the frontend with JavaScript. I have got a overview page, where all products are shown. After clicking on the detail button, the user should be able to view the details of the selected product. For this i use this code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./Articles.css";

function ArticleDetail({ match }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchArticle();
  }, []);

  const [article, setArticle] = useState([]);

  async function fetchArticle() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/articles/${match.params.id}`
      );
      const article = await response.json();
      //console.log(data.results);
      console.log(article);
      setArticle(article);
      return article;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>TEST</p>
      <p>{article.articles.pk_article_nr}</p>
      <p>TEST</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ArticleDetail;
```

If i run this code and don't refresh the page by myself, the correct value (pk_article_nr) is shown. If i refresh the browser manually there is this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pk_article_nr')

This data are shown in the console:

```
{articles: {…}}
  articles:
    article_description: "lorem ipsum"
    article_expiretimestamp: "2022-01-15 18:52:27"
    article_picture: null
    article_timestamp: "2022-01-15 18:37:27"
    article_title: "Test 4"
    bid_amount: 80
    fk_article_nr: 4
    fk_user_userid: null
    pk_article_nr: 4
    pk_bid_id: 8`
```

Could you please help me? I haven't found anything that helps me. Maybe i just searched for the wrong thing.

Thank you,
Max

Comment: Remove the first article. from article.articles.pk_article_nr

Comment: Make sure you use optional chaining like `article?.articles?.pk_article_nr`. It will help you to avoid some error.

Comment: Hey @Grumpy,
thanks for your advice. Now it is showing 

Failed to compile
src\components\ArticleDetail.js
  Line 29:11:  'articles' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Greetings,
Max

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React returns "Cannot read property "name" of undefined." (Fetch API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68881990/react-returns-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined-fetch-api)

Comment: @max, my bad, didnt look right at the source.

Comment: Hey @AlokPrakash,
now it's working. Thank you. I will try to understand why.
Cheers, Max

Comment: Since you are new I will recommend Optional Chaining, Spread Operation and Object/Array destructuring which will help you very much in react. Also, It will short the number of your code line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should change

```html
<p>{article.articles.pk_article_nr}</p>
```

to

```html
<p>{article?.articles?.pk_article_nr}</p>
```

Reason for this to happen:

> React wants to access the property before mounting, while the property has not yet received any content

Comment: Hey @Reza Mohabbat,
now it's working. Thank you. I will try to understand why.
Cheers, Max

Comment: @max Good luck.

Comment: @RezaMohabbat can you add some more detail to your answer to indicate why this would solve the specific issue (I'm aware of why myself, but for future readers it might be helpful).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Dr_Derp Yes, Sure!

Comment: Thanks! It might also be useful to provide some info on optional chaining, since that seems to be the star here.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. "React wants to access the property before mounting" - no it doesn't. Please delete your answer.